# How to save video as frames in list and process the list of frames simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I want to read input from camera and append frame in a list, display the frame from list.  The code takes much time to read a frame and display it, after appending into the list.

```
def test(source_file):
    ImagesSequence=[]
    i=0
    capture = VideoCapture(source_file)
    while(1):
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        while(True):
            imshow('Input', frame)

            ImagesSequence.append(frame)
            imshow('Output',ImagesSequence[i].astype(np.uint8))
            i=i+1
        if cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    return ImagesSequence

test(0)
```

Comment: you have an (actual) infinite loop there. this is a beginner issue. you should work through basic programming tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Christoph pointed out, you have an actual infinite loop running in the program, removing it will fix your program.

```
def test(source_file):
    ImagesSequence=[]
    i=0
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(source_file)

    while True:
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        cv2.imshow('Input', frame)
        ImagesSequence.append(frame)
        cv2.imshow('Output',ImagesSequence[i].astype(np.uint8))

        i=i+1
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    return ImagesSequence

test(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from cv2 import *
import numpy as np
ImagesSequence=[]
i=0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    ImagesSequence.append(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY))
    cv2.imshow('output', ImagesSequence[i].astype(np.uint8))
    i=i+1
    if cv2.waitKey(60) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```